# Apply multiple header styles in header "options" prop react native

Tags: react-native

Here is my screen:

```
<Stack.Screen 
    name="accountType" 
    options={[({route} => {
    title: route.params.username,
    {headerStyle}

)]}>
```

As you  can see, I'm trying to include the `route` paramenter and my  `headerStyle`  variable together.

```
const headerStyle = {
    headerShown: true,
    headerTintColor: 'black',

    headerLeft: (props) => <BackArrow color={'black'} />,

    transitionSpec: {
      open: {
        animation: 'timing',
        config: {
          duration: 70,
        },
      },
      close: {
        animation: 'timing',
        config: {
          duration: 70,
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Any idea how to make these work?

Comment: what is headerStyle ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan It's a variable. Just updated my code. You'll see that I include  it within the ```options``` prop in the stack screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below, this will add the headerStyle along with the params

```
options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.username,...headerStyle })}
```

Full code would be like below

```
    <Stack.Screen
      name="accountType"
      component={AccountType}
      options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.username,...headerStyle })}
    />
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Can you explain the dot notation?

Comment: ok so the options expect an object, so we spread the object that you have along with the title you provide, if you have a default title in your custom object then the title should be added after that. you can get more info from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax